# Search strings in Excel Column & Delete the column in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to this forum so please excuse if this is not the right channel.

I am looking for some help in searching the strings which are in Excel Column Header "$Col4 / $Col6 / $Col7 / $Col19 / $Col22 / $Col27" and if found, then delete the entire column.

The concern is if I am changing the line as per below then it goes into loop but reads only Row 1 of the sheet. But if I keep as per the below code then because it reads all the $col value as Row 1, it gives the result as "Nothing found".

```
if (($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col4) -or ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col6) -or ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col7) -or ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col19) -or ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col22) -or ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col27)) {

$column++


$Col4 = 'Col4'

$Col6 = 'Col6'

$Col7 = 'Col7'

$Col19 = 'Col19'

$Col22 = 'Col22'

$Col27 = 'Col27'

$Results = "C:\Temp\Results.xls"

$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false}

# open Excel file

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($Results)

$sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

$row = 1

$column = 1

$found = $false

# Search for /TESTOut in A1

$info = $sheet.cells.Item($column, $row).Text

# Write-Host $info

if($info -eq "/Test"){

$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the first row

}

$WorksheetRange = $sheet.UsedRange

$RowCount = $WorksheetRange.Rows.Count

$ColumnCount = $WorksheetRange.Columns.Count

While ($row -ne $RowCount) {

If ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col4) {

$column++

If ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col6) {

$column++

If ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col7) {

$column++

If ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col19) {

$column++

If ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col22) {

$column++

If ($sheet.cells.Item($row,$column).text -eq $Col27) {

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Found match at Row: " $row # Replace this line to delete the Column

$found =$true

}

}

}

}

}

}

Else {

$row++

$column = 1

}

}

If (!($found)) {

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Nothing found" # This is for test purpose only. Do Nothing.

}

$workbook.Close($true) # Close workbook and save changes

$excel.Quit() # Quit Excel

[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) # Release COM
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a simple counting loop running backwards:

```
# columns to delete
$deleteThese = 'Col4', 'Col6', 'Col7', 'Col19', 'Col22', 'Col27'

$file  = 'C:\Temp\Results.xls'
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
# open the Excel file
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet    = $workbook.ActiveSheet
# get the number of columns in the sheet
$colMax   = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

# loop through the columns to test if the column header is found in the $deleteThese array
# do the loop BACKWARDS, otherwise the indices will change on every deletion.
for ($col = $colMax; $col -ge 1; $col--) {
    $header = $sheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value2
    if ($deleteThese -contains $header) {
        $null = $sheet.Columns($col).EntireColumn.Delete()
    }
}

# save and exit
$workbook.Close($true)
$excel.Quit()
# clean up the COM objects used
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```